# Do order of lines matter when applying inference rules?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

The wikipedia shows the form of Modus ponens as

```
1. If P, then Q.
2. P.
3. Therefore, Q.
```

With `1` being the implication and `2` being the antecedent of that implication.

When applying the rule, I would cite the lines in that order

```
1. p -> Q       Hypothesis
2. P            Hypothesis
3. Q        1,2 Modus Ponens
```

Would it be impure form for me to instead write

```
1. p -> Q       Hypothesis
2. P            Hypothesis
3. Q        2,1 Modus Ponens
```

With the order of the arguments to be plugged into the Modus Ponens function reversed?

Or should you always cite lines in the order corresponding to the form definition, regardless of the order they actually appear in the proof?

```
1. P            Hypothesis
2. p -> Q       Hypothesis
3. Q        2,1 Modus Ponens
```

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Something to think about : In general over-view , Modus Ponens is actually something like this :: $1 \land 2 \implies 3$ , where we can use commutativity of $\land$ to get $2 \land 1 \implies 3$ :: In other words , the order will not matter.

Comment: I can see how some person or proof system software could demand the lines cited in a certain order, but it seems super nit-picky: it takes very little intelligence to figure out whether the cited lines can be fit the pattern of Modus Ponens or any other elementary inference in one order or some other. So, I wouldn't worry about the order in which you cite lines, unless explicitly told it does have to follow a certain order.

Comment: As Bram points out, yes, the order could matter.  But, often the premises used in an inference rule get taken as a set.  Since it's a simple matter of set theory that changing order of the elements of a set does not change the set (or equivalently sets have no order), the order of premises in an argument or use of a rule of inference does not matter.